# iOS: -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -sectcreate

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, llvm, libtool-xcode

my goal is to build a static iOS library with bundled resources. I have been doing this successfully on OS X years ago, but I am running into an issue here.

I am adding my resource with a linker flag:

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -sectcreate __DATA __FOO resouces/foo.bin
```

The Xcode 4.6 libtool gives me the error:

```
libtool: -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -sectcreate __DATA __FOO resouces/foo.bin
```

I have seen similar questions here, but always in the conjuction with the -ObjC flag. Is the -dynamic flag required for -sectcreate these days? Am I doing it wrong?

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can't include resources with static libs. Since shared libraries are not supported in iOS, you'll have to live with this limitation.
Quoting from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/configuration.html)
"Static libraries cannot include resources directly, but a static library project can provide resources which an application can reference and include in its Copy Bundle Resources phase."

Comment: I know you did not write the docs, but how exactly can't that? I can add a data section with -sectcreate as mentioned above, and I can access that section from my code. That is not exactly the most elegant, or Apple-like way of referencing resources, but it works perfectly (when it works)